# Can I decrypt my SD card with another phone?

Tags: encryption, decryption, sd-card

I found [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/143943/76718) in an old 2016 post, and I have the same problem.

I encrypted my SD card and when I unencrypted my phone, I didn't realize I needed to unencrypt the SD card first. To be honest, I probably would have forgotten to anyway, I was already so frustrated as I had someone in my phone and this was my latest attempt to get them out.

I was wondering if you needed to use the same phone that you encrypted the  card on to do what you are suggesting or can you use a totally different phone.

I have recently given said phone to a friend in another state who had a dinosaur phone. In fact I am trying to get the unlock code for it now.

I appreciate any help as this card contains important data. I realize I should have done backups, but I couldn't at the time.

Answer (score 7):

To decrypt the SD card, you need the decryption key.

Since every Samsung device has an unique hardware key, you need to use the same device you've used for encryption.

I'm afraid that your only option is to ask your friend to use your previous phone to decrypt the SD card.

Be sure to follow [the steps in the answer you linked](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/143943/76718) to prevent an irreversible data loss.